# How to print a full content of JScrollPane?

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing, jscrollpane

I am just a designer and don't know javascript well enough to figure out how to print a full content of a JScrollPane, not a visible part of it.
I would very much appreciate any help with the issue.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest creating a print-stylesheet that contains following rules:

```
div.jScrollPaneContainer {
   position: static !important;
   height: auto !important;
   overflow: visible !important;
}

div.jScrollPaneContainer > * {
   display: none !important;
}

div.scroll-pane {
   position: static !important;
   display: block !important;
   float: none !important;
}
```

all selectors used in the code above correspond to HTML structure of [jScrollPane basic example](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/basic.html)

Answer (score 1):

Didn't work for me with jScrollPane - v2.0.0beta11 - 2011-07-04.
Taking a quick look at the generated source code shows that the div class names have changed.
Here is what I put in my print.css:

```
div.booksummary,  
div.booksummary > div {
  position:static !important;
  height: auto !important;
  overflow: visible !important;
}
```

where the jQuery code is:

```
$('.booksummary').jScrollPane();
```

Another thought : Putting CSS properties in @media print {} only works if the CSS file in question is loaded, which won't happen if the CSS file is associated to the 'screen' media.

Answer (score 0):

Or put the entire scrollpane stylesheet inside a

```
@media print
{
 //scrollpane css goess here.

}
```