# Printing the full content of a div when using jScrollPane jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery-jscrollpane

We are using jQuery jScrollPane plugin v2.0.  When a page is printed only the content visible inside a scrollable area are printed.  We would like to get the entire page content printed instead of only the visible content.  Is there a CSS way to do this?

I have already seen and tried [How to print a full content of JScrollPane?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570906/how-to-print-a-full-content-of-jscrollpane) but am still unable to print the entire content.

**Update:**
I have had some luck getting this to work with the following CSS:

```
@media print {
.jspContainer,.jspScrollable,.jspScrollable>* {
    height: auto !important;
    overflow: visible !important;
    overflow-x: visible !important;
    overflow-y: visible !important;
    position: relative !important; }
}
```

This works well on all browsers except IE.  overflow-x and overflow-y are required specifically by Google Chrome (I am on v18.0.1025.168) and Apple Safari (v5.1.5), while simply overflow works well on Firefox and Opera.

Any suggestions on how things can be made to work on IE as well?  The problem, as I mentioned above is that with IE only the content visible inside the scrollable area gets printed instead of the entire content.

Comment: Interesting... the `CSS` you provided worked for me in IE 8 at least. Thanks... :)